# Best way to check for positive integer (PHP)?

Tags: php, validation

I need to check for a form input value to be a positive integer (not just an integer), and I noticed another snippet using the code below:

```
$i = $user_input_value;
if (!is_numeric($i) || $i < 1 || $i != round($i)) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

I was wondering if there's any advantage to using the three checks above, instead of just doing something like so:

```
$i = $user_input_value;
if (!is_int($i) && $i < 1) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: the last check is only to see if the number is a integer. Using this check really depends on your requirements

Comment: ...You are checking for a negative number in the code currently.

Comment: Fixed! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

the difference between your two code snippets is that `is_numeric($i)` also returns true if $i is a **numeric string**, but `is_int($i)` only returns true if $i is an integer and not if $i is an **integer string**. That is why you should use the first code snippet if you also want to return true if $i is an **integer string** (e.g. if $i == "19" and not $i == 19).

See these references for more information:

[php is_numeric function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php)

[php is_int function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

Comment: Just trying that code out, I am finding even that is not enough, since it validates `'   123'` as an integer. I needed to add `$i !== trim($i)` to catch leading spaces. It seems that ' 123' == '123' even when you are sure the two values are strings, but PHP does not treat them as strings when comparing them that way.

Comment: Notice that query string values (GET parameters) are always passed as string, even if the value if numeric.

Answer (score 55):

Not sure why there's no suggestion to use [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) on this.  I know it's an old thread, but maybe it will help someone out (after all, I ended up here, right?).

```
$filter_options = array( 
    'options' => array( 'min_range' => 0) 
);


if( filter_var( $i, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $filter_options ) !== FALSE) {
   ...
}
```

You could also add a maximum value as well.

```
$filter_options = array(
    'options' => array( 'min_range' => 0,
                        'max_range' => 100 )
);
```

Learn more about [filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).

Comment: Note that this will still accept numeric strings like `'123'`. If you want to disallow zeros, set `min_range` option to 1.

Comment: FILTER_VALIDATE_INT doesn't return false for the string '+5'.

Comment: 0 is not a positive integer, so I would set min_range to 1.

Comment: That's what the lack of type safety has driven the language into.

Answer (score 28):

The best way for checking for positive integers when the variable can be INTEGER or STRING representing the integer:

```
 if ((is_int($value) || ctype_digit($value)) && (int)$value > 0 ) { // int }
```

`is_int()` will return true if the value type is `integer`. `ctype_digit()` will return true if the type is `string` but the value of the string is an integer.

The difference between this check and `is_numeric()` is that `is_numeric()` will return true even for the values that represent numbers that are not integers (e.g. "+0.123").

Comment: +1 seems by far the cleanest - it also works with super long strings made of digits. (Even when this string starts with `-`)

Comment: Note that it treats numerical strings with leading zeros (i.e. `'00123'`) as integers, while `FILTER_VALIDATE_INT` does not.

Answer (score 15):

It's definitely heading towards the land of micro-optimisation, but hey: the code I'm working on chews through millions of items every day and it's Friday.  So I did a little bit of experimenting...

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++) {
    // Option 1: simple casting/equivalence testing
    if ((int) $value == $value && $value > 0) { ... }

    // Option 2: using is_int() and ctype_digit().  Note that ctype_digit implicitly rejects negative values!
    if ((is_int($value) && $value > 0) || ctype_digit($value)) { ... }

    // Option 3: regular expressions
    if (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $value)) { ... }
}
```

I then ran the above tests for both integer and string values

**Option 1: simple casting/equivalence testing**

- Integer: 0.3s
- String: 0.4s

**Option 2: using is_int() and ctype_digit()**

- Integer: 0.9s
- String: 1.45s

**Option 3: regular expressions**

- Integer: 1.83s
- String: 1.60s

Perhaps unsurprisingly, option 1 is by far the quickest, since there's no function calls, just casting.  It's also worth noting that unlike the other methods, option 1 treats the string-float-integer value "5.0" as an integer:

```
$valList = array(5, '5', '5.0', -5, '-5', 'fred');
foreach ($valList as $value) {
    if ((int) $value == $value && $value > 0) {
        print "Yes: " . var_export($value, true) . " is a positive integer\n";
    } else {
        print "No: " . var_export($value, true) . " is not a positive integer\n";
    }
}

Yes: 5 is a positive integer
Yes: '5' is a positive integer
Yes: '5.0' is a positive integer
No: -5 is not a positive integer
No: '-5' is not a positive integer
No: 'fred' is not a positive integer
```

Whether or not that's a good thing for your particular use-case is left as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 5):

The other best way to check a Integer number is using regular expression. You can use the following code to check Integer value. It will false for float values.

```
if(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$i)) {
  // valid input.
} else {
  // invalid input.
}
```

It's better if you can check whether $i > 0 too.

Comment: this will return `TRUE` also for `0`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to use all three check and if you want a positive integer you might want to do the opposite of what is in your code:

```
if(is_numeric($i) && $i >= 0) { return true; }
```

Check Sören's answer for more information concerning the difference between `is_int()` and `is_numeric()`

Answer (score 3):

```
    preg_match('{^[0-9]*$}',$string))
```

and if you want to limit the length:

```
    preg_match('{^[0-9]{1,3}$}',$string)) //minimum of 1 max of 3
```

So pisitive int with a max length of 6:

```
    if(preg_match('{^[0-9]{1,6}$}',$string)) && $string >= 0)
```

Comment: does the preg_match allow negative int?

Comment: Another interesting approach... but this is harder to read, so I'd probably be less apt to use it.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(preg_match('/^[1-9]\d*$/',$i)) {
   //Positive and > 0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than checking for `int` OR `string` with multiple conditions like:

```
if ( ctype_digit($i) || ( is_int($i) && $i > 0 ) )
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

you can simplify this by just casting the input to `(string)` so that the one `ctype_digit` call will check both `string` and `int` inputs:

```
if( ctype_digit( (string)$i ) )
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the other answers: You are probably looking for [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit). It looks for a string containing only digits.

Answer (score 2):

Definition:

```
!A = !is_numeric($i)
B = $i < 1
!C = $i != round($i)
```

Then...

!is_numeric($i) || $i < 1 || $i != round($i)  **is equal to** 
!A || B || !C

So:

```
!A || B || !C = !A || !C || B
```

Now, using the deMorgan theorem, i.e. (!A || !C) = (A && C), then:

```
!A || !C || B = (A && C) || B
```

Now, note that A && C = is_numeric($i) && $i == round($i), but if $i == round($i) is TRUE, then is_numeric($i) is TRUE as well, so we can simplify A && C = C so,

(A && C) || B = C || B =

```
$i == round($i) || $i < 1
```

So you just need to use:

```
$i = $user_input_value;
if ($i == round($i) || $i < 1) {
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To check for positive integer use:

```
$i = $user_input_value;
if (is_int($i) && $i > 0) {
  return true; //or any other instructions 
}
```

OR

```
$i = $user_input_value;
if (!is_int($i) || $i < 1) {
  return false; //or any other instructions 
}
```

Use the one that fits your purpose as they are the same. The following examples demonstrate the difference between `is_numeric()` and `is_int()`:

```
is_numeric(0);     // returns true
is_numeric(7);     // returns true
is_numeric(-7);    // returns true
is_numeric(7.2);   // returns true
is_numeric("7");   // returns true
is_numeric("-7");  // returns true
is_numeric("7.2"); // returns true
is_numeric("abc"); // returns false

is_int(0);     // returns true
is_int(7);     // returns true
is_int(-7);    // returns true
is_int(7.2);   // returns false
is_int("7");   // returns false
is_int("-7");  // returns false
is_int("7.2"); // returns false
is_int("abc"); // returns false
```

Comment: `is_int` checks variable type. It is not applicable to user's input because in most cases it is string.

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel 4.2 Validation rule for positive number**

It takes only positive numbers including float values.

```
public static $rules = array(
    'field_name' => 'required|regex:/^\d*\.?\d*$/'
);
```

e.g:20,2.6,06

Answer (score 1):

The first example is using `round` to verify that the input is an integer, and not a different numeric value (ie: a decimal).

is_int will return false if passed a string.  See the [PHP manual examples for is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php)

Answer (score 1):

All these answers overlook the fact that the requestor may checking form input.
The is_int() will fail because the form input is a string.
is_numeric() will be true also for float numbers.
That is why the $i == round($i) comes in as it checks for the input being a whole number.

Comment: Saying "All these answers" is a stretch. I see some answers prior to yours that use regular expressions, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I know this thread is really old but I share @Jeffrey Vdovjak's opinion: since I was able to find it, it might still help someone else out there.

php's gmp_sign() might be another easy way to check. It works for integer and numeric strings, and returns 1 if a is positive, -1 if a is negative, and 0 if a is zero.

So:

```
// positive
echo gmp_sign("500") . "\n";

// negative
echo gmp_sign("-500") . "\n";

// zero
echo gmp_sign("0") . "\n";
```

will output:

```
1
-1
0
```

See function manual at http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-sign.php

P.S. You'll need to have php_gmp.dll enabled in your .ini file.

Answer (score 1):

This's my solution, hope helpful :

```
if (is_numeric($i) && (intval($i) == floatval($i)) && intval($i) > 0)
   echo "positive integer";
```

i check if string is numeric, second check to sure it's integer and third to sure it positive

Answer (score 0):

If you use "is_int" the variable must be integer, so it can't be a float value. (no round needed).

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($i) && is_int($i) && $i >= 0){ //0 is technically a postive integer I suppose
    return TRUE; //or FALSE I think in your case.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
if ((int) $i > 0) {
    // this number is positive
}
```

The number gets typecast to a positive or negative number depending on the minus sign being at the front. Then compares the typecast number to being greater than 0 to determine if the number is positive.

Comment: The question is to test if a value is a positive **integer**. Your proposed solution  will return `true` for any value which when cast to an integer results in a positive value including, but not limited to, positive float values and the boolean literal `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but the top answers here did not take into account leading zeroes. And if you are in search of a way to check for positive integers without leading zeroes (think of default autoincremented values, e.g. MySQL ID columns, starting from 1) that might also be numeric strings (contained in a URL, such as an HTTP GET parameter), here are two alternatives:

```
function isNumericId($input): bool
{
    return ctype_digit($input) && $input[0] != 0;
}
```

Using a regular expression:

```
function isNumericId($input): bool
{
    return preg_match("/^[1-9][0-9]*$/", $input) === 1;
}
```