# Do I really need regular expression to check if input field is integer?

Tags: php, integer, validation

I have a form, and I need to check out if some values are integer. This seems unexepctedly complicated.

I tried:

```
if (is_int($value))
```

this doen’t work: any value return false, because the text input always sends a string type variable

```
if (is_numeric($value))
```

this works, but only check if variable is numeric. I want to know if it is an integer, so I don’t want that 1.3 is accepted.

```
if (is_int( (int) $value ))
```

Tried to use is_int, and force cast $value as integer. This doesn’t work either

So, unless there is some other solution which I’m not aware of, I guess the only way is to use 
     `ereg("^[0-9]*$",$value)`

Is there any problem with this (performance?), and aren’t there really more straightforward solutions?

Kind regards.

Comment: What you try does not conform with the description of the functions. That is why it does not work. Additionally to not doing that type of homework with the manual, you also didn't search. This has been asked and answered before.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance for form validation. Also I would consider adding client-side validation to eliminate the round-trip to the server. Still do server-side validation, but if you can eliminate work on the server, that is better performance improvement than any minor reduction in per-request processing time.

Comment: There's also [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/ctype_digit)

Comment: Loosely related: [Best way to check for positive integer (PHP)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844916/best-way-to-check-for-positive-integer-php?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, hakre I did search but didn’t found the post you linked (through the answer I needed’s not given there, even if the idea was found in the user’s question itself :) ), the only thing I did found was the regular expression solution. I did read the manual, as I said I understand why is_int() doesn’t work, I was just wondering what to use instead. @Alan, thanks, I’ll add of course the client side validation as well

Comment: ctype_digit() is perfect, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by **mario**, [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) is the single, function way to go:

```
if (ctype_digit($_POST['value'])) {
  $for_santity = (int)$_POST['value'];
}
```

Simple. Fast. Reliable.

Comment: Thanks, this work just fine and it’s the single expression I was looking for.

Comment: if someone is using a version of php incompatible with ctype_digit, they could do `if( intval($_POST['value']) > 0 ){ return ( floatval($_POST['value']) == intval($_POST['value']) ) ? 'true' : 'false'; }`

Comment: `ctype_*` only requires C (which isn't even a requirement as so does PHP). And has been enabled by default since version 4.2.

Comment: I guess it just isn't working in the online IDEs I've been using. @JasonMcCreary

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the regex (not sure what `strpos` it does under the covers)

```
if(!strpos($value,'.') && is_numeric($value))
```

> You've essentially replicated ctype_digit()

It appears I have, apologies as PHP is not my native language.  Use the following as we shouldn't be recreating library functions:
`if(ctype_digit())`

Comment: You've essentially replicated `ctype_digit()`.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that ctype_digit() is the optimal answer, but I post this answer just in case someone is using a version of PHP that doesn't support the function (like in my test case: Ideone.com):

```
<?php
function testInt($a){
    if (intval($a)>0) {
        return (floatval($a)==intval($a)) ? 'true' : 'false';
    }
    return 'false';
}
?>
```

This works with the examples listed on the [ctype_digit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) page.

Here is an online example: http://ideone.com/uePQto

Answer (score 0):

How about this,

```
 if( is_numeric( $value ) && floor( $value ) != $value)
```

Performance measure is too trivial in this case.

Comment: I didn’t think to that. Nice! Thank you very much.

Comment: PS: The first one works, the second one you added doesn’t, as I explained in the question: it was the first version I tried :)

Comment: It does, take a look at the *Demo*.

Comment: It doens’t if the number is of a string type (which is the case if the value is passed through form), as you can see here [link](http://codepad.org/rkLEsOnO). :)

Comment: @coder1984 In his question he states that the input "always returns a string type variable". Your solution would always return false.

Answer (score 0):

You could try defining the data type of the received information. Lets say you are getting the information from a form via POST:

```
$num_val = (int) $_POST['VALUE_FROM_FORM'];
```

and I think that is_int will return the right result but you have to make sure the result received is numeric.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP you could check the value with `preg_match`, don't use the old `ereg` functions as they are deprecated.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (!preg_match('/^[0-9]*$/', $id)) {
    // there was an error and the value DIDN'T pass validation
} else {
    // continue as everything was OK :)
}
```

You may have to change the `GET` to `POST` or `REQUEST` to suit.

Comment: Your code validates empty strings as correct, and negative integers as incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've always dealt with integers that I expected to be 1 or more (i.e. for incoming vars that are supposed to represent an unsigned primary INT key):

```
$var = intval($_POST['form_var']);
if($var > 0){
    echo 'Good';
}
```