# How to check a query string is a positive integer in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, query-string

I am passing some numeric values in query string and I need to check if the passed value is only positive string i.e. Should be greater than 0 and without decimals.

```
if( !(is_int($url_segments['cid']) && is_int($url_segments['bid'])))
{
 show_error('ERROR :: CID and BID should be positive integers only');
 return FALSE;
}
```

The above check returns false if I pass `?cid=3&bid=4` in query string.

How can I check for positive integers?

Comment: $x>0 = $x is positive

Comment: @Ja͢ck Yes $url_segments is an alias of $_GET : $url_segments = array(); $url_segments['bid'] = (isset($_GET['BID'])) ? $_GET['BID'] : 0;  $url_segments['cid'] = (isset($_GET['CID'])) ? $_GET['CID'] : 0;

Comment: @Dagon $x > 0 will pass the float number which is false in my case

Comment: From the duplicate question, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15277806/1338292) is arguably the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, if you need int values use ctype_digit()

```
if (! (ctype_digit($url_segments['cid']) and ctype_digit($url_segments['bid']))
and (ctype_digit($url_segments['cid'])<=0 or ctype_digit($url_segments['bid'])<=0) ) {

}
```

Comment: Doesn't check whether it's a positive integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( !(is_numeric($url_segments['cid']) and is_numeric($url_segments['bid']))) {

}
```

Comment: `is_int` not `is_numeric`

Comment: "I am passing some numeric values"

Comment: i guess "string is a positive integer" is just an oxymoron, so its a good as idea as any

Comment: @Dagon Using `is_int()` will not be useful because it won't be an integer :)

Answer (score 0):

if(is_numeric($_GET['cid']) && $_GET['cid'] >= 0 && is_numeric($_GET['bid']) && $_GET['bid'] >= 0)
{

return TRUE;
}